# Não consigo mudar de diretório no Git Bash

Tags: diretório, linha-de-comando

Eu tento navegar entre os diretórios mas não consigo, já tentei de tudo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Depois de `cd` tem que ter espaço: `cd /Users`

Comment: @hkotsubo, no caso do `git bash`, o _root_ é uma espécie de diretório artificial (diferentemente do terminal padrão unix) que contém, entre outras coisas, "diretórios" onde estão montadas as partições. Então `cd /c/` vai colocar o terminal na raiz do diretório `c`, já `cd /Users` não está definido. Você quis dizer `cd /c/Users`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Perfeito, tinha esquecido desse detalhe do `/c`. Então são 2 problemas: a falta do espaço depois de `cd` e o acesso incorreto  à raiz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O git bash já inicia por padrão no diretório do seu usuário, quando ele estiver no diretório padrão ao invés de mostrar todo o caminho por exemplo: `/c/Users/Gustavo` ele mostra apenas um: `~`, quando você estiver em outro diretório e quiser ir para o diretório padrão você pode digitar o seguinte comando: `cd ~`, caso você esteja em um diretório e não sabe o conteúdo que tem nele você também pode usar o comando `ls` para listar os arquivos e pastas no diretório que você está atualmente.

Comment: Só o comando `cd` tem o mesmo efeito do comando `cd ~`. Por sinal, o `~` não é algo do comando `cd`, mas uma expansão específica do `bash`, a _expansão tilde_, voltada para acessar arquivos na `home` sua ou de outrem. Por exemplo, se há permissão do Gustavo para ler do usuário Jeff o arquivo `teste.txt`, o Gustavo poderia usar `cat ~Jefferson/teste.txt`, que o `bash` vai expandir isso para `cat /c/Users/Jefferson/teste.txt` e só então chamar o comando `cat`

Comment: Eu sei que o cd e o ~ são duas coisas separadas, mas eu não sabia que somente o cd iria para home e o ~ poderia acessar outras home claro se tiver as permissões, obrigado.

Comment: Valeu, ajudou de mais!

Answer (score 1):

o comando correto é `cd Users/Gustavo` existe um espaço entre cd e o diretório para se acessar.

Comment: Isso só é o correto de `$PWD` for `/c`. Em outro diretório ele não irá para o local desejado, que é a pasta do usuário `Gustavo` no sistema Windows